# what happens to UDP packets not read?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, buffer

In C, I have a simple server/client UDP socket programming example. 
The client sends packets to the server at a high rate, while the server reads each incoming message and sends it back to the client.
The client will never read any incoming messages.

Is there any reason to believe that packets sent back to the client will **fill up** the client's **buffer**? What actually happens to them if the client doesn't read anything? Will they get **dropped** instantly?

Comment: Why? Why isn't the client reading messages that the server isn't sending? Why is the server sending messages that the client isn't reading? What's the point of doing it wrong? Just hoping the network will behave nicely in the face of your mis-design isn't much of a strategy.

Comment: Yo, why did you close my question? It is a perfectly fine one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel will queue the incoming packets up to some limit, which may be controllable on the client by setting the SO_RCVBUF socket option.  When the limit is reached, additional packets will be dropped and the kernel may send a Source Quench ICMP message back to the sender.  There's no standard way of controlling that on a per-socket basis.  If Source Quench messages are sent, you may be able to read them on the server by using the IP_RECVERR socket option.

If you do nothing, then Source Quench messages (if sent) will probably just be ignored, though it is possible that the server's kernel could trigger an error on the sending socket.  I'm not aware of any OS that does anything like that, however.

In general, sending data that is unwanted is wasteful and shouldn't be done -- the client packets could contain a single bit telling the server whether the client is expecting a response, thus avoiding the whole issue.

Answer (score 6):

The kernel will put packets into socket's *receive buffer* expecting the application to read them. When that buffer fills up the kernel starts dropping new datagrams.